# Multiple connection strings in Connections.config based on different machines [c#]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, connection-string

For our project (which is in a git repo) we have a Connections.config with the connection string to the local database. However, for our online repository in the server, which has its own tests on CI, we have to use a different connection string such that the online master branch code can connect to the CI's database to execute the tests.

How can we have multiple connection strings in the Connections.config such that based on the machine the code being executed choses the appropriate connection to the database?

Note: We can not use the option of .gitignore such that Connections.config is not changed.

Current Issue: When we are pushing our local connection string changes to the master branch, the connection string online is getting set to our local database connection while overriding the connection string for the server tests. I know putting Connections.config in gitignore should fix this but we can not put this file in gitignore (for some business decison). So is there a way to have multiple connection strings in the config such that different connection can be used based on the machine it is being executed?

Example of connection string locally:

```
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="sqlServer"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Example of connection string on the server for tests:

```
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="sqlServer"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Put two connection strings in the file (two `add` elements with different `name` values), and then write some code in your app to decide on which one to use.

Comment: Use connection strings in your code behind, make them dynamic so its calls the correct server name based on the machine name (ServerVariables)..

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using Azure, you can store them in KeyVault. Then setup your environments with the correct value. For local development, store your values using the [secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows) file.
- If you are using a config file, you shouldn't because of security risks